# Unfortunately Your application has stopped

Tags: android, android-intent

i am trying to switch from one activity to other using intents, first activity is running properly but when second activity starts the app gets stopped. i have attached the code with this.

**Manifest :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sampleapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    ...

    <application
        ...


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sampleapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sampleapp.welwithname"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.WELWITHNAME" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        ...

    </application>

  </manifest>
```

this is the default activity. i tried to get the string and send it to the next activity.here is the xml and activity.
   **Activity Code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.sampleapp.MESSAGE";

    String tempname;
    Button submit;
    EditText name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        submit= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

         submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Welwithname.class);
                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.getname);
                String message = editText.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                startActivity(intent);
             }
         });

    }


}
```

**Second Activity:**

this activity gets the string from activity 1 and print the value..heres the xml and activity
**Activity Code:**

```
public class Welwithname extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welwithname);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText("Welcome" + message + "!!!" );
        Button sq = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sq);
        Button exit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exit);

        sq.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View V)
            {
                Intent main = new Intent(Welwithname.this,MainScreen.class);
                startActivity(main);
            }

        });

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }

    ...

}
```

what changes should i made in this code to make it run?

Comment: Please edit your post and turn of CAPS LOCK.  Also post the logcat stack trace for the exception.  Finally, separate your XML and code.  Don't just format everything as one block.  Help us to read the question so that we can help.

Comment: also, make sure your actual question is not in the 'code' tags, add your error log and try to remove all parts of the code we don't need for this question. Add what your code is supposed to do, why you expect it to do that etc.

Comment: Look at this question for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740635/why-getview-not-getting-called

Comment: You won't get any answers if you do not post the stack trace.

Comment: I think i deserve an applause for editing this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.sampleapp.welwithname"
```

Isn't your class called `Welwithname` ?

capitalise the 'W' in the Activity name in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

---

You are not going to be a developer long if you do not read the console / logcat output when you come across a crash.

If you read your LogCat it is most likely saying "Cannot find Activity welwithname, have you declared it in your Manifest?" and that would be your answer and StackOverflow would be a happier place

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html